# Validating a field before submitting

Tags: javascript

I have a text field and a button.

I want to validate the field, and if the validation fails, **the button should not "submit".**

This is my button:

```
<input type="submit"  onsubmit="return validate()"
```

And this is my validation function:

```
function validate()
{
    var number = document.getElementById("temp");
    alert (number.value);

    if ( /^[0-9]{12}$/.test(number.value) ) 
    { 
        alert(number);
        return true;
    }
    alert ("מספר הפנייה חייב להיות בן 12 ספרות");
    return false; 
}
```

But it wont work, the submit occures any way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onsubmit` event should be attached to the `form` object, not the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this:

```
<form id = "myform" onsubmit="return validate()" action = "mypage.php">


<input type="submit">

</form>
```

This should work...